# Excel Smart Table as datasource for pivot

Tags: excel, range, pivot, datasource, named

I have a Workbook D:\Sales.xlsx with a sheet named Orders. In this sheet there is a smart Table (Ctrl + T) named **tbl**Orders.
In another Workbook E:\Reports.xlsx there is a sheet pvtOrders. When I create a pivot in this pvtOrders sheet and give D:\Sales.xlsx!tblOrders as datasource, it works fine while the source workbook Sales.xlsx is open in the **same Excel instance**. When the source is closed or opened in other Excel instance however refreshing of the pivot-Table is not working anymore. Excel prompts "Invalid reference" or similar (tested in Excel 2010, 2013).

The same problem is with a "normal" named range as source for the pivot table. However in this case there is no error prompt.

Is it a normal behavior? Is there a simple solution or at least a workaround without opening the source?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

from my experience you need to have them open. have you considered merging both files? it might make things easier.

Comment: Merging is unfortunately not a choice. They have to be separate. Any further ideas? Thanks